# Moving the woocommerce checkout account register

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration, checkout

my goal is to move the checkout user registration form to the top of the checkout page (Above the billing form)...

I'm stuck on finding the correct variables and names to hook this form to the place I desire.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify `form-billing.php` template.

move the following code to the top or the place you want.

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $checkout->is_registration_enabled() ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-account-fields">
        <?php if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_required() ) : ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide create-account">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" id="createaccount" <?php checked( ( true === $checkout->get_value( 'createaccount' ) || ( true === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false ) ) ), true ) ?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <span><?php _e( 'Create an account?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>

        <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="create-account">
                <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' )  as $key => $field ) : ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll most definitely use this as my back up but are there any ideas on how i can do this in my functions.php?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this in functions.php, you need to override the template.